# Visual Studio Template Project Output Path Name

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-templates

I have a template project that I use to start new projects and I want to use them side by side. Their namespaces are updated according to the project name that I enter when I create them so there is no namespace clash however all of them has same output path by default, (same path of the original template solution.) How can I parametrize them so dll's will have same name with the created project names but not the template names? I plan to create multiple projects quickly so don't want to give output path manually each time. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at T4 templating.

Answer (score 0):

The output path of a project is stored in the .csproj file. In your template, the .csproj file probably contains a fixed output path for your build.

When you remove that output setting, the compiler will take a default which differs per project so they won't interfere anymore.